ql.OvernightIndexFutureRateHelper asking for a fixing, but not able to add it
I´m trying to make a Overnight Index FutureRateHelper but when bootstrapping, the following Error arises:
RuntimeError: 1st iteration: failed at 1st alive instrument, pillar May 31st, 2024, maturity May 31st, 2024, reference date May 9th, 2024: missing rate on May 1st, 2024 for index TIIE_OISTN Actual/360
import numpy as np
import QuantLib as ql
import calendar

ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = ql.Date(9,5,2024)
ibor_MXNTIIE_oi = ql.OvernightIndex('TIIE_OIS',
                                    1, 
                                    ql.MXNCurrency(), ql.Mexico(),
                                    ql.Actual360())

fixing_dates = ['30/04/2024', '02/05/2024', '03/05/2024',  
                        '06/05/2024','07/05/2024', '08/05/2024']

fixings = [11.07, 11.02, 11.05, 11.01, 11.00, 11.01]        


ibor_MXNTIIE_oi.clearFixings()

ibor_MXNTIIE_oi.addFixings([ql.Date(d, '%d/%m/%Y') for d in fixing_dates], 
                           (np.array(fixings)/100).tolist())

fwd_quotes = [88.94, 88.9801, 89.2003, 89.1606]
month_year = [(5, 2024), (6, 2024), (7, 2024), (8, 2024)]

helpers = []
for d, q in zip(month_year, fwd_quotes):
    
    priceQuote = ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(88.94))
    month = d[0]
    year = d[1]
    last_day = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[-1]
    
    startDate = ql.Date(1, month, year)
    
    endDate = ql.Date(last_day, month, year)
                                 
    
    helpers.append(ql.OvernightIndexFutureRateHelper(
        priceQuote, startDate, endDate, ibor_MXNTIIE_oi))
    
    
crvTIIE = ql.PiecewiseNaturalLogCubicDiscount(0, ql.Mexico(), 
                                              helpers, 
                                              ql.Actual360())

fwd_rate = crvTIIE.forwardRate(ql.Date(9,5,2024), ql.Date(10,5,2024),
                               ql.Actual360(), ql.Simple).rate()

I tried ading the fixing for 1 of May of 2024, but this other error arises:
RuntimeError: At least one invalid fixing provided: Wednesday May 1st, 2024, 0.1102
This is the code I used:

import numpy as np
import QuantLib as ql
import calendar

ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = ql.Date(9,5,2024)
ibor_MXNTIIE_oi = ql.OvernightIndex('TIIE_OIS',
                                    1, 
                                    ql.MXNCurrency(), ql.Mexico(),
                                    ql.Actual360())

fixing_dates = ['30/04/2024', '01/05/2024', '02/05/2024', '03/05/2024',  
                        '06/05/2024','07/05/2024', '08/05/2024']

fixings = [11.07, 11.07, 11.02, 11.05, 11.01, 11.00, 11.01]        


ibor_MXNTIIE_oi.clearFixings()

ibor_MXNTIIE_oi.addFixings([ql.Date(d, '%d/%m/%Y') for d in fixing_dates], 
                           (np.array(fixings)/100).tolist())

fwd_quotes = [88.94, 88.9801, 89.2003, 89.1606]
month_year = [(5, 2024), (6, 2024), (7, 2024), (8, 2024)]

helpers = []
for d, q in zip(month_year, fwd_quotes):
    
    priceQuote = ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(88.94))
    month = d[0]
    year = d[1]
    last_day = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[-1]
    
    startDate = ql.Date(1, month, year)
    
    endDate = ql.Date(last_day, month, year)
                                 
    
    helpers.append(ql.OvernightIndexFutureRateHelper(
        priceQuote, startDate, endDate, ibor_MXNTIIE_oi))
    
    
crvTIIE = ql.PiecewiseNaturalLogCubicDiscount(0, ql.Mexico(), 
                                              helpers, 
                                              ql.Actual360())

fwd_rate = crvTIIE.forwardRate(ql.Date(9,5,2024), ql.Date(10,5,2024),
                               ql.Actual360(), ql.Simple).rate()




Can someone please explain or tell me how I can workaround this issue

I guess that May 1st is a public holiday in Mexico. If you drop that date, does it work then?

Yes! That is the issue. But the future is of all the month including the first and last day regarding if it is a holiday or not. When I make the helpers, the bootstraing fails because the Index doesn't have fixing the 1st of May.

I copied your code, dropped the May 1st value, and it worked on my end. Maybe I misunderstand your problem, though.

Let me add the bootstrapping part of the code

I edited it yesterday

I did not fully walk through your code; I just dropped the May-1st-fixing date and also set the ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate - then it worked.

Does it work when you set the evaluationDate to 2024/5/9?

No, then it says 'negative time', sorry. I hope my comments did not waste your time, though.

Don't worry. I still have the same issue
